# Trouble creating Bootable USB Drive

Tags: 16.04

Running Rufus creating a bootable disk using iso image. When starting the program an error message appears stating

```
ERROR:ISO image extraction failure.
```

This occurs when the syslinx operation is starting.

Tried multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ISO image may be corrupted or incomplete. You can check the SHA1 cryptographic hash from your ISO in Rufus, by clicking the **#** button at the bottom of the interface. Then go back to the webpage where you downloaded the ISO image and search for the checksum hashes for that ISO image. You can find links to the checksum hashes for official Ubuntu versions at [Ubuntu Hashes - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

[image]

Comment: Downloaded File was incomplete. Downloaded again and ran Rufus. All went well and now I have a bootable USB Drive.

Comment: Sorry for not getting here sooner. Did as you said karel and thanks for that info. Is there a way to add something to the OP Title stating the topic is CLOSED OR RESOLVED?

Comment: The accepted answer is always at the top of the list regardless of how many votes the accepted answer got, so it's easy to tell if a question has an accepted answer, and marking a question that has an accepted answer as closed or resolved in any other way would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the .iso file yourself, then it sounds as though the .iso file is damaged or incomplete.  Try downloading the file again, and verify that the SHA256 hash for the downloaded file is correct according to the instructions [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify).  (In my opinion you can skip the steps to get the signature key and verify the signature.)  When the `sha256sum` tool (or equivalent tool in whatever OS you're running now) says "OK", then you'll know that the .iso file is 100% complete and correct, and you can proceed to use Rufus to make a bootable USB drive.